# Conditionally apply functions to value in sequence

Tags: haskell

If I have a value and I want to apply multiple transformations to it using monads, I can do this,

```
func3 =<< func2 =<< func1 value
```

but if I want each function to execute conditionally, this is the way I think it could be done.

```
applyFuncs value = do
  if condition1
    then value' <- func1 value
    else let value' = value
  if condition2
    then value'' <- func2 value'
    else let value'' = value'
  if condition3
    then value''' <- func3 value''
    else let value''' <- value''
  return value'''
```

However, writing this is tedious, so I looked for a solution online, but somehow I was unable to find anything of use. Is there maybe a library function that I can use like this?

```
when' condition3 func3 =<< when' condition2 func2 =<< when' condition1 func1
```

Comment: Well, the `when'` you are supposing is just `when' p f x = if p x then f x else pure x` It's not defined in the standard library, but you can define it yourself (and perhaps use a different name, like conditionalBind or something similar, so you don't clash with `Control.Monad.when`). Not sure how much of an answer this is because you are looking for a *library* function, so I put this in as a comment.

Comment: If, as I think, `conditionN` can depend on all the previous values, this is hard to generalize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have:

```
value :: a
f1, f2, f3 :: a -> a
cond1,cond2,cond3 :: a -> Bool
```

You said you can do it with a monad.  Why not use a monad?

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.State
whenM f op =
       do s <- f <$> get
          if s then op else pure ()
all3 :: a -> a
all3 val = flip execState val $
    do whenM cond1 $ modify f1
       whenM cond2 $ modify f2
       whenM cond3 $ modify f3
```

Or don't and just make a helper or two:

```
all3again :: Int -> Int
all3again val =
    ite cond1 f1 val
    |> ite cond2 f2
    |> ite cond3 f3

ite :: (a -> Bool) -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
ite c a v | c v = a v
          | otherwise = v

(|>) :: a -> (a -> b) -> b
(|>) v f = f v
infixl 5 |>
```